# Mockery TypeError when mocking class

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

I'm trying to create a mock object and pass it in to a constructor. I'm getting the error

```
Users            
 ✘ GetUser ItShouldThrowAnExceptionIfUserDoesNotExist
   ┐
   ├ Failed asserting that exception of type "TypeError" matches expected exception "Foo\Exceptions\UserNotFoundException". Message was: "Argument 2 passed to Foo\Clients\Users::__construct() must be an instance of Foo\Api\UsersApi, instance of Mockery_0__UsersApi given, called in /Users/tomcaflisch/myproject/tests/Clients/UsersTest.php on line 25" at
   ├ /Users/tomcaflisch/myproject/lib/Clients/Users.php:26                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   ├ /Users/tomcaflisch/myproject/tests/Clients/UsersTest.php:25                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   ├ .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   ┴
```

According to [the docs](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html#classes-abstracts-interfaces) this should work.

Users class

```php
class Users
{
    public function __construct(?string $secret, UsersApi $usersApi = null)
    {
    }
```

UsersTest class

```php
use Mockery\Adapter\Phpunit\MockeryTestCase;

class UsersTest extends MockeryTestCase
{
    public function testGetUser_ItShouldThrowAnExceptionIfUserDoesNotExist()
    {
        $this->expectException(UserNotFoundException::class);
        $this->expectExceptionMessage("User with id, email, or username foo@bar.com not found");

        $usersApi = Mockery::mock('UsersApi');
        $usersApi->shouldReceive('get')
            ->andThrow(new UserNotFoundException("User with id, email, or username foo@bar.com not found"));

        $usersClient = new Users(null, $usersApi);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Ah I just figured it out. I need to use the full namespace.

i.e.

replace

```php
$usersApi = Mockery::mock('UsersApi');
```

with

```php
$usersApi = Mockery::mock('Foo\Api\UsersApi');
```

Comment: Or `$usersApi = Mockery::mock(UsersApi::class);`, if you have it imported (`use`).

Comment: This just caught me out as well. Its amazing how we rely on the IDE to import classes for us, and when it doesn't, it takes ages to work out the issue. Or maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

I usually go this route:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Services\ServiceToBeMocked;
use App\Services\ServiceToBeTested;
use App\Jobs\JobToBeTested;
use Mockery;
use Mockery\MockInterface;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ServiceToBeTestedTest extends TestCase
{
    private ServiceToBeTested $testService;

    public function testSomePartThatDoesntUseTheInjectedDependency(): void
    {
        /** @var ServiceToBeMocked $mockService */
        $mockService = Mockery::mock(ServiceToBeMocked::class);

        // now you can use it
        $this->testService = new ServiceToBeTested($mockService);

        // continue with testing

        // assert things happened
    }

    public function testSomePartThatUsesTheInjectedDependency(): void
    {
        // The part you're testing actually uses the mocked service
        // by calling its method mockedMethod, which should in this
        // given test return 'a-string-value'

        /** @var ServiceToBeMocked $mockService */
        $mockService = Mockery::mock(ServiceToBeMocked::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('mockedMethod')
                ->andReturn('a-string-value');
        });

        // now you can use it
        $this->testService = new ServiceToBeTested($mockService);

        // continue with testing

        // assert things happened
    }

    public function testSomethingThatUsesServiceToBeMockedInAJob(): void
    {
        // In this case we don't need to assign it to a variable
        Mockery::mock(ServiceToBeMocked::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('mockedMethod')
                ->andReturn('a-string-value');
        });

        // JobToBeTested::handle(ServiceToBeMocked $mockService)
        app()->call(JobToBeTested::class . '@handle);

        // assert things happened
    }
}
```